# If statement issue with basic python program [python]

Tags: python-3.x

I a new in programming , was trying some concepts with if else in python
The if else statement is not working as it should.
I'm using nested if-else , however only included the basic code in the code block
I am using a string as an input and then comparing the input with if else statements.
I tried the code in Thonny ide and it works when I debug the program , but after trying to run the program it does not print anything .
 Alternatively if I use an else statement instead of the elif in the end , only the code in the else statement will print

---

---

the code is :

```
new_value = input("enter your choice between left and right")

if new_value =='left':
 print("You chose left")
elif new_value =="right":
 print("you chose right")
```

Comment: Is it possible you're adding whitespace to the start of your input to make it "appear" correctly in the terminal? That would cause the strings to not be equivalent.

Comment: Removed the whitespace. It worked . Thank you . can you please explain what happens if the whitespace is kept there .

Comment: It's simply that the strings aren't equivalent. To a computer, `test` is not the same as `test `, because there are use cases where that needs to be the case. To circumvent this when it's not wanted, Python provides methods like `str.strip`, which removes leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Got it . Thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 1):

This code is correct.

```
new_value = input("enter your choice between left and right")
if new_value =="left":
 print("You chose left")
elif new_value =="right":
 print("you chose right")
```

Alternatively if you use an else statement reffer it,

```
if new_value =='left':
 print("You chose left")
else:
 print("you chose right")
```

provide your full nested loop so i will understand problem.